# What is the best option for a continuous background thread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to write an application that listens to things in the background and displays things on the UI based on what it hears. I was looking at the options available and AsyncTask is one of them. However it says use it only for short bursts of work. What is the best way to have a continuous background operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Service is what you're looking for: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

And in your case, probably one that is running on the foreground: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground